# What does the eye symbol mean in this gmail email title?

Tags: gmail

[image]

I can't tell what this eye symbol is supposed to mean. There's no obvious rhyme or reason. As you may be able to tell, I receive some emails via ifttt, but the majority of them do not have this eye symbol.

Comment: I think this is Google ad that come in Gmail. The ads changes from time to time according to your search history on Google.

Comment: It was an email. There are several more.

Comment: It may be a Chrome Extension called Ugly Mail. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a [Google Chrome Extension](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/187443?hl=en) that you're using called [Ugly Mail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/uglyemail/ldgiafaliifpknmgofiifianlnbgflgj). [Read more about it [here](http://www.wired.com/2015/03/ugly-mail/)]

Comment: haha, so this is one of those chrome extensions I read about, thought was a good idea, then forgot about. Thanks.

Comment: @knl: If this provided the solution to your question, you should use the checkmark to mark it as "accepted". This will act as a signpost for future readers with the same question. See: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)